# Virtual Sd-card won't transfer

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have a Verizon Galaxy Nexus 32GB. I've installed AOKP on it and it has been running pretty okay with no bugs etc...

But after I connected it too my Nintendo Wii I think it mounted sdcard as FAT32 itself :\

I'm receiving the following error when trying to download something from 4Shared sync app(But actually none can download or transfer anything to Virtual sdcard):

> XXXXX.apk: open failed: EACCES(Permission denied)

I already restored my old backup wiped all data etc, nothing seems to work.

Note that I can access my sd-card, i can't only transfer, take pics... basically data.

PS: I showed 4sync problem because it was the only one that specify something

Comment: Can you make some aspects clearer? The question is a little unclear to me. From what I read i suppose you have not connected it to the Wii any more and still have the problem with the sdcard accessibility. Please provide logcat debug output https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat or install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm and do a 'mount', 'dmesg', 'logcat' command there and see what problem you have. Post your findings here. By the way: Doesn't the GNexus forbid SDcard mounting as FAT32? I think there's only MTP and PTP transfer modes.

Comment: Idk, but i'm almost sure it did because of that error.
I can use adb, so logcats are easily provided, i also already saw one of 'em and i've found no problems with storage...
I tried mounting, not working, nothing about sd-card works

Comment: I'm confused. Galaxy Nexus doesn't have a SD card. Do you mean you somehow got it to mount the /sdcard/ folder to your wii and then *that* formatted your /sdcard/ directory?

Comment: Sorry,basically the Galaxy Nexus does have a "virtual sd-card" that isn't data wiped with the data factory reset from CWM, for me the only option was to downgrade the phone to a stock version, as it locked and unlocked partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically the Galaxy Nexus does have a "virtual sd-card" that isn't data wiped with the data factory reset from CWM but it is when wiped via stock recovery, for me the only option was to downgrade the phone to a stock version, as it locked and unlocked partition. But there are other ways to do it, but all of 'em includes formatting your "sd-card"(sad).